# Significato di piano in una frase

Tags: adjectives, sentences

Ho una domanda: quando dico

> *L'uomo parlava piano*

l'aggettivo 'piano' ha un significato di *parlava lentamente* oppure *parlava a bassa voce*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In questa frase, "piano" può avere entrambi i significati: "lentamente" e "a bassa voce" (entrambi corretti: http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/piano1/). È il contesto a far capire quale dei due significati si intende.

Comment: Per mia esperienza "parla piano!" significa di solito "abbassa la voce!", ma è vero che entrambi i significati sono corretti.